# Rails how to change attribute name when rendering json?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In my controller  I have:

```
@pakkes = Pakke.where("navn like ?", "%#{params[:q]}%")

respond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.erb
  format.xml  { render :xml => @pakkes }
  format.json { render :json => @pakkes.map(&:attributes) }
end
```

How do I change the attribute `navn` to `name` when rendering JSON?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can do this with a one-line method in `Pakke`:

```
def as_json(*args)
    super.tap { |hash| hash["name"] = hash.delete "navn" }
end
```

Calling `super` will generate json hash as usual, then before it's returned you'll swoop in and change the key of the "navn" entry.

Comment: This is an elegant and super cool solution! Thanks for that :)

Comment: great solution, handy for those protected attributes that conflict with old IE versions...

Comment: not removing my column neither adding one in hash. Although it looks fine but it is not working.

Comment: works also in 2023

Answer (score 3):

Override the [as_json](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON/as_json) method. It's used by `to_json` in order to produce the output. You can do something like:

```
def as_json options={}
 {
   name: navn,
   .... # other attributes you want to add to json
 }
end
```