# Changing attribute name in record objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, hash, attributes

I have a query that selects a record of groups from a table.

```
@groups = Group.all
```

One of the attributes, `id`, is incompatible for the front-end framework that handles the JSON that is sent to it from the controller.

My question is after I have the list of groups in `@groups`, how could I change out the id for each attribute to a different name, i.e. `group_id`?

I won't be using this for views or anything else, I just need to change the key name `id` to `group_id`.

For example, let's say I run `@groups.first`. It should return...

```
=> #<Group id: 1, owner_id: 81, name: "my awesome group", updated_at: "2013-04-23 20:58:27", created_at: "2013-04-23 20:58:27">
```

When I format this to json I have the key value `id: 1`. In reality I need it to be `group_id: 1`.

Comment: why in the world do you need that?

Comment: It's a long story. Thank Objective-C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override the name in the `as_json` method of the `Group` class:

```
def as_json(*args)
    super.tap { |hash| hash["group_id"] = hash.delete "id" }
end
```

See:
[Rails how to change attribute name when rendering json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8948787/rails-how-to-change-attribute-name-when-rendering-json)

Comment: Your skills at searching are far better than mine.

Answer (score 1):

You could abuse the ActiveRecord [`select`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-select) method:

```
@groups = Group.select("id AS group_id, owner_id, name,...")
```