# Migration: How to add alias name for reference column

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This following is a example:

I add a to belongs_to column to my migration:

```
create_table :meetings do |t|
    t.string :meeting_name
    t.belongs_to :user
end
```

And will generate a **user_id** to my meetings table.

And i will render meeting to JSON, like this:

```
{
  "meeting":{
    "meeting_name":"this is a meeting name",
    "user_id":1
  }
}
```

But the **user_id** attribute and **meeting.user** is not friendly.

**I want :**

> define an alias name for **user_id**

The JSON will be:

```
{
  "meeting":{
    "meeting_name":"this is a meeting name",
    "creator":1
  }
}
```

And **meeting.user** will become to **meeting.creator**

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8948787/rails-how-to-change-attribute-name-when-rendering-json

Comment: I think this answer should help you:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/417320/scaffolding-activerecord-two-columns-of-the-same-data-type

Answer (score 3):

change your migration to:

```
create_table :meetings do |t|
    t.string :meeting_name
    t.integer :creator_id
end
```

change your model to

```
class Meeting < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :creator, :class_name => 'User'
end
```